After update from Expo SDK 51 to Expo SDK 52, barcode scanner has removed. I try to implement barcode scanner with expo-camera but having error
When I try to implement expo-camera for barcode scanning, i get the error that below. How should I solve the problem? Can anyone help me? My expo sdk version and expo-camera versions are "expo-camera": "~16.0.7",     "expo": "^52.0.0",
'''
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Alert, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc, updateDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getCurrentUser } from './backend';

export default function QRCodeScanner({ navigation }) {
    const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(false);
    const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getPermissions = async () => {
            const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
            setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
        };

        const fetchUser = async () => {
            const user = await getCurrentUser();
            if (user) {
                setCurrentUser(user);
            } else {
                navigation.navigate('Login');
            }
        };

        getPermissions();
        fetchUser();
    }, [navigation]);

    const handleBarCodeScanned = async ({ data }) => {
        if (scanned) return;
        setScanned(true);

        try {
            const url = new URL(data);
            const tableId = url.pathname.split('/').pop();
            const db = getFirestore();
            const tableDocRef = doc(db, 'tables', tableId);
            const tableDoc = await getDoc(tableDocRef);

            if (!tableDoc.exists()) {
                Alert.alert('Error', 'Table does not exist');
                setScanned(false);
                return;
            }

            const tableData = tableDoc.data();
            const userId = currentUser?.id;
            const userName = `${currentUser?.name || ''} ${currentUser?.surname || ''}`;

            if (!userId) {
                Alert.alert('Error', 'Current user is not defined');
                setScanned(false);
                return;
            }

            if (!tableData.player1) {
                await updateDoc(tableDocRef, { player1: userId, player1Name: userName });
                navigation.navigate('PlayerOptions', { gameId: tableDoc.id, playerNumber: 'player1' });
            } else if (!tableData.player2) {
                await updateDoc(tableDocRef, { player2: userId, player2Name: userName });
                navigation.navigate('Scoreboard', { gameId: tableDoc.id, playerNumber: 'player2', player1Name: tableData.player1Name, player1Ball: tableData.player1Ball, player2Name: userName });
            } else {
                Alert.alert('Error', 'Table is already full');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error connecting as player:', error);
            Alert.alert('Error', 'Permission denied. Please check your Firebase rules.');
        } finally {
            setScanned(false);
        }
    };

    if (!hasPermission) {
        return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Camera
                style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
                onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
            />
            {scanned && <Button title="Tap to Scan Again" onPress={() => setScanned(false)} />}
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});

'''
***(NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
Check your code at QRCodeScanScreen.js:81.
in QRCodeScanner (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by DebugContainer)
in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SceneView)
in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))
in Animated(Anonymous)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
in Unknown (created by ScreenStack)
in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent)
(NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
Check your code at QRCodeScanScreen.js:81.
in QRCodeScanner (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by DebugContainer)
in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SceneView)
in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))
in Animated(Anonymous)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
in Unknown (created by ScreenStack)
in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent)
(NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Warning: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
Check the render method of QRCodeScanner.
This error is located at:
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by QRCodeScanner)
in QRCodeScanner (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by DebugContainer)
in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SceneView)
in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))
in Animated(Anonymous)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
in Unknown (created by ScreenStack)
in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent)
(NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Warning: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
Check the render method of QRCodeScanner.
This error is located at:
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by QRCodeScanner)
in QRCodeScanner (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by DebugContainer)
in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SceneView)
in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))
in Animated(Anonymous)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
in Unknown (created by ScreenStack)
in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent)***
